# Get only X number of categories

Tags: posts, categories

How can i get only x number of categories using `the_category`.  I triesd a few thing but none worked. I dont want to use `get_the_category`

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. `the_category` and `get_the_category` do exactly the same, however, the first function prints the cat, the second returns it. So, do you want to A) **get** or B) **print** P) **X posts of a certain category** or Q) **X categories** of the existing ones, or something else?

Comment: the reason is that the_category gives me the result in ul li format as well as categories are linked to theris permalinks. I dont want to do iteration using get_the_category and increase unwanted work!

Comment: The work, as far as the server is concerned, should be about the same whether you loop through the categories or whether [`the_category` does](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/category-template.php#L154) so your concern about unwanted work may not be relevant, but maybe you are talking about the work that you have to do.

Answer (score 1):

After reading your question (and comment) again, this could be what you want to do:

```
$X = 3; // for instance
ob_start();
the_category();
$cats = implode('<li', array_slice(explode('<li', ob_get_clean()), 0, $X+1));
```

If you want to use this throughout your theme multiple times, use a function. Put the following in your `functions.php`:

```
function my_the_category($limit) {
    $limit++;
    ob_start();
    the_category();
    $cats = implode('<li', array_slice(explode('<li', ob_get_clean()), 0, $limit));
}
```

Now you can use `<?php my_the_category(3); ?>`, for example.